# How do you get the file referenced in the declaration of lotusscript that is part of the %INCLUDE

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We have several applications that include a specific '.lss' file that was created years ago by a vendor that isn't on any of the Domino servers and no employee has a copy.  Since the applications are working in our production environment all is good, but when we need to make a code change we get an error because we don't have that file in our installation path to be compiled.

Is there a way to get the contents of the file from an application in our production environment since that is a compiled version of the 'nsf'?  Does the file also need to be on the server somewhere if the application is working in our production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall the exact process that is involved (it's been over a decade since I did it), but some vendors that want to hide their code use LSS files. They compile it into script libraries and agents, and distribute only the compiled version. If this is the case for the code you're looking for, it's not going to be possible to recover the LSS file.

Comment: You're absolutely right: Without access to the lss file from the original developer there is no way to get that code back...